# How to handle unpredictable and unwanted pop up appears in selenium webdriver even t is not expected behavior

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In our application we are getting pop up some times but it is not expected behavior, once this pop up displayed remaining scripts will get fail as focus is on pop up. So can you please guide me to resolve this issue

Comment: You should raise a bug in the product you're testing, and work on a clean branch, not try to work around the problem in your tests. That just complicates your tests, and conceals the problem rather than helping it get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If it is happening in the same place a lot you can deal with it like this...

```
public boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
        driver.switchTo().alert();
        return true;
    } // try
    catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    } // catch
}
```

Now, you can check whether alert is present or not by using the method written above as below:

```
if (isAlertPresent()) {
    driver.switchTo().alert();
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```

I wouldn't put this everywhere though because it will really slow down the tests.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is -
Create a function that will be used to access any element for ex-

```
getButton("xpath of your desired xpath").click();

getButton(String Xpath){
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath()).isVisible)
return driver.findElement(By.xpath())
else{
if (isAlertPresent()) {
    driver.switchTo().alert();
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}
return driver.findElement(By.xpath())
}

}
```

MAke sure you always make call to this function to access any element from UI .